# Change webBrowser to webView2 c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, webview2

I must upgrade webBrowser control in my program to webView2 because many pages are not working anymore.
I have a method that returns the inner text of the activelement

```
 if (XtraMessageBox.Show(this, "Text:\r\n\r\n" + 
                    webBrowser.Document.ActiveElement.InnerText + "\r\n\r\n" +
                    "will be added to description", 
                    "DESCRIPTION UPDATE", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    .Equals(DialogResult.No))
                return;

            descriptionMemoEdit.EditValue += webBrowser.Document.ActiveElement.InnerText;
```

I am trying to find an equivalent to webView2 but I cant find anything.
I tried

```
webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.ActiveElement.InnerText").ToString()
and 
webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.ActiveElement.InnerText").ToString()
```

but it just returns
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String] and not the actual text.
I saw that webView2 doesnt have DOM.
How can I get the innertext?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this.

```
await ExecuteScriptAsync("your script here...");
```

Don't forget to put await.

EDITED :

Add a webView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted event to your webview2.

On your event add this sample code.

```
private void webView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            this.webView21.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted += CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted;

        }
```

Then add some method.

```
 private async void CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
                {
    await webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("your script here...")
    ;}
```

Comment: It still returns System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]

Comment: Try using my edited answer if it is working or not.

Comment: Those events are fired when the page is initialized. I want to return the text of the active element which means that I must use something when the user clicks on a text and then presses a button. I need a return method that has the inner text of the activeElement.